# How can I gracefully pass state to the back click of my components?

Tags: angular, navigation, router

I have a simple scenario.

I am registering a component in my Angular2 app.module config.

```
routes = [ 
{ path: "/home", component: HomeComponent, data : { info : "hello world" }];
```

Now, I want to call the same page passing a variable version of info with a different value based on some conditions so that I can animate left or right? I tried many thing including the following, non of which have worked for me.

```
router.navigate(["/home", {info : "hello again" }]);
```

After further inspection I noticed that the **data** in the route is for static information only which kind of puts a wrench in my plans. The whole idea is that when I click the back button I could pass some data into the click for all pages which sets a flag to use the back animation rather than the forward animation which has a slide left or right transition.

This leaves me with only a few considerations which include none that seem appealing. Duplicate route definitions, "no way!" guards to pass a variable to every component, "pretty much no go territory!". The last which I was trying to avoid is a global variable. I don't see any elegant solutions otherwise. I am sure they are out there but I feel blinded currently.

Comment: Why not route params? `path: "/home/:msg" you can then give each route param a separate animation id act on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Router** and **ActivatedRoute** to communicate data between 2 components.

The caller will do the following :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'caller-component'
})
export class CallerComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  navigate(){
    //called when a specific link is clicked in the template
    let extraData: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: {
        "prop1": "Hello Home!",
        "prop2": "I am back"
      }
    };
    this.router.navigate(['/home'], extraData);

  }

}
```

Then your home component will need to learn how to intercept those parameters:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'home-component'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      //Do something here with the values you receive
      console.log(params.prop1);
      console.log(params.prop2);
    });
  }

}
```